# powershell Get-Process with ComputerName is missing Path

Tags: powershell

I want to get a list of processes under specific folder on some remote machine and kill them. However, if I add -ComputerName, Get-Process does not return Path as desired, thus I cannot Where with Path. Is there a way to Get-Process / Stop-Process on remote machine under a specific path?

```
// Paths are filled
PS C:\> Get-Process | Format-Table Name, Path
Name                                                        Path
----                                                        ----
firefox                                                     C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe

// Paths are empty
PS C:\> Get-Process -ComputerName localhost | Format-Table Name, Path
Name                                                        Path
----                                                        ----
firefox
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Invoke-Command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx) if Remoting is enabled on the remote server, and perform your action in the scriptblock of the command:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName remoteComputer -Script { param($pathFilter) Get-Process | ?{$_.Path -like $pathFilter} | Format-Table Name, Path } -Args "somefilter*"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case that I resolved by using x64 version of powershell.